# data format and uploading issue

Tags: r, delimiter, dataformat

Here is a snippet of data I have to analyze:

`2014 log[1]: id="1" sys="Sec" sub="fill" severity="inf" dort="30" 
2014 log[2]: id="2" sys="Sec" sub="fill" severity="inf" name="dropped"`

Excuse me if this is an obvious question, but what kind of data is this, and how can I get it into a csv format to analyze? So far I have tried using R by specifying whitespace as the delimiter, but that didn't get me what I need:

`table1<-read.table('data.txt', sep="", fill=TRUE, header = FALSE)`

Ideally, `"id", "sys", "sub", "severity", "dort"`, and `"name"`would be the column headers. Each row contains about the same number of variables, but some rows do not contain variables that other rows do. For those instances, I would like there to be "NULL". Ex: In row two in the data above, under the `dort` column I would like it to say "NULL"

Comment: Can you provide more than 1 line of sample data? Does each line have the `id`, `sys` etc tags?

Comment: @Drj edited for clarity

Comment: In your example, in row 2 I don't see `dort`. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @i.n.n.m, Yes, thats the problem I'm having. Not all rows have the same number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
id="1" sys="Sec" sub="fill" severity="inf" dort="30" 
id="2" sys="Sec" sub="fill" severity="inf" name="dropped"
```

Let's consider that `test.txt` has above mentioned data then

```
library(rjson)
library(plyr)

#prepare json data
txt_file <- readLines("test.txt")
json_file <- lapply(txt_file, function(x) paste0('{"', gsub(',', ',"',gsub("=",'":',gsub('"\\s+', '",', gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$","",x)))), '}'))
json_file <- paste0("[", paste(json_file, collapse=","), "]")

#read json data
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)

#convert it to dataframe
df <- rbind.fill(lapply(json_data,function(y){as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))
df[df=='NULL'] <- NA
df
```

Output is:

```
  id sys  sub severity dort    name
1  1 Sec fill      inf   30      NA
2  2 Sec fill      inf   NA dropped
```

Comment: @cheesetaco Welcome to SO! You should mark the satisfactory answer as the correct answer if that answers your query as it'll help others in case they face similar issue in future. Thanks!

Comment: Just got to this -- but thank you! You are a lifesaver, this worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)